# How do you use Connect.js methods if you're running Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, connect.js

I'm using Node with Express. Express has Connect kinda buried within it. How do you call Connect's various methods though? When I require Express then doing express.middleware.someconnectmiddleware fails...

Comment: `express.connectMiddleware` should be the same as `connect.connectMiddleware`

Answer (score 2):

They're all available on express under the same name.

```
express.bodyParser == connect.bodyParser
```

Comment: Then why does app.use(express.utils); fail? Why does express.utils.parseSignedCookie(cookie, 'secret'); fail? I get "TypeError: Cannot call method 'parseSignedCookie' of undefined"

Comment: utils isn't public so it's not exported. http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/. you can ask TJ about that, I would actually like that as well.